# Azure blob storage migration with huge data in each container with decryption

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to migrate encrypted *blobs* from source Azure *storage account* to destination storage account in *decrypted format* (Key vault key).

I have written C# code but it was taking almost 3 days for single container. I am trying event grid triggered azure function connected to destination storage account on new file captured event and migrating blobs using Azure data factory copy pipeline, azure function is using app service plan which can scale out till 10 instances.

am I on right path? is there any other performant way?

Comment: Disregarding my deleted answer, if you need to decrypt them, maybe you are on the right track, loading them into a bus or queue and using a function that can and scale horizontally

Comment: Also, if you need to scale more, spin up a AKS cluster and write a small container to read from a queue and process each file. In this way you are basically unlimited to how much this can scale (well depending on your subscription). Just be wary, this will easily drill a hole in your wallet

Answer (score 1):

If your Azure function need is only to initiate ADF pipeline, then I guess you can take advantage of event based trigger or you can opt of LogicApp to do the same job for better performance.

Event-driven architecture (EDA) is a popular data integration paradigm that entails event creation, detection, consumption, and response. Data integration situations frequently need users triggering pipelines based on storage account events, such as the arrival or deletion of a file in an Azure Blob Storage account.

Please check below link to know more about event based triggers: Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event | [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory)

Also, you can consider increasing DTUs/Parallel copy options as well inside copy activity which helps you to improve performance of your copy.

If there is a need to migrate a big amount of data from a data lake or an enterprise data warehouse (EDW) to Azure. Other times, you may need to import huge volumes of data into Azure from several sources for big data analytics. In each scenario, achieving optimal performance and scalability is important.

Please check below link to know more details about : [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance)